# run java thread continously after it ends

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class that runs as a thread, and I would like to run in again once it finishes executing, and possibly, maintain two-three threads of the same class running at the same time (ie. if a thread finishes executing but two are running, only one is run again, and so on).

The code I tried is this:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 );
while( true )
    pool.submit( new MyThread() );
```

Any feedback on how this can be achieved?

Update: the class MyThread is actually MyRunnable!

Many thanks, 
Vlad

Comment: It is not recommended to start a thread more than once. You can create a new instance of the same thread and start it, but not the same one.

Comment: An `ExecutorService` runs `Runnable`s or `Callable`s, not `Thread`s.  If you can show more of your code maybe we can help.  What are you trying to run repeatedly?

Comment: @andersoj `Thread` is `Runnable`.

Comment: Yah, I got that a Thread is a Runnable but that doesn't mean it's a good idea to have a thing that might be running in its own thread and submitting it to be (confusingly) run in yet another thread by the executor.  (Or more concisely, see @Evgeniy's answer...)

Comment: @andersoj Yes, you are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html):

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
CompletionService<Void> compService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Void>(executor);

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) compService.submit(new Task(), null);

while(true)
{
    compService.take(); // wait until one of the threads finishes its task
    compService.submit(new Task(), null);
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to be the exact thing I was looking for, many thanks, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    pool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("running1");
            pool.submit(this);
        }
    });

    pool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("running2");
            pool.submit(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: wait! I actually tested this throughly  and it stops after the three threads runs, this won't restart after a thread ends

Comment: I changed the test to make it clear which task is actually executed. Seems OK. All tasks run non-stop. You can add task3

Comment: It's cool idea, but this way the `Runnable` object will be the same all the time.